# python-telegram-bot - does not transfer to the required state

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Good Afternoon! I don’t understand why it doesn’t transfer #1 to another state. Help me please!

```
VACATION_DAYS_IS_TRUE = 'IF_IS_TR'
VACATION_DAYS_IS_FALSE = 'IF_IS_FA'
STATE_SEND_INFO_START = 0
STATE_VACATION_DAYS_TRUE = 1
STATE_VACATION_DAYS_FALSE = 2
STATE_TIME_OFF_DAYS_TRUE = 3
STATE_TIME_OFF_DAYS_FALSE = 4
STATE_SICK_DAYS_TRUE = 5
STATE_SICK_DAYS_FALSE = 6


def make_keyboard_for_send_info_step_1():
    buttons = [[
        InlineKeyboardButton('TRUE', callback_data=f'{VACATION_DAYS_IS_TRUE}'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('FALSE', callback_data=f'{VACATION_DAYS_IS_FALSE}')
    ]]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)


def send_info_per_month_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text(
        text='some_text',
        reply_markup=make_keyboard_for_send_info_step_1()
    )
    return STATE_SEND_INFO_START


def send_info_start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    #1 - After return must move to another handler
    return STATE_VACATION_DAYS_TRUE if query.data == VACATION_DAYS_IS_TRUE else STATE_VACATION_DAYS_FALSE


def make_changes_vacation_days(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    #2 Here - depending on the answer
    query = update.callback_query
    query.edit_message_text(text="Here")


def make_changes_time_off_days(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    #3 Or Here - depending on the answer
    query = update.callback_query
    query.edit_message_text(text="Or Here")


def setup_dispatcher(dp):
    """
    Adding handlers for events from Telegram
    """
    conv_handler_send_info_per_month = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("send_info_per_month", send_info_per_month_command)
        ],
        states={
            STATE_SEND_INFO_START: [CallbackQueryHandler(send_info_start)],
            STATE_VACATION_DAYS_FALSE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, make_changes_vacation_days)],
            STATE_VACATION_DAYS_TRUE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, make_changes_time_off_days)],
            STATE_TIME_OFF_DAYS_TRUE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, make_changes_time_off_days)],
            STATE_TIME_OFF_DAYS_FALSE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, make_changes_time_off_days)],
            STATE_SICK_DAYS_TRUE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, make_changes_time_off_days)],
            STATE_SICK_DAYS_FALSE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, make_changes_time_off_days)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CallbackQueryHandler(fallback)],
        per_message=False
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler_send_info_per_month)
    return dp


def run_polling(tg_token: str = TELEGRAM_TOKEN):
    updater = Updater(tg_token, use_context=True)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp = setup_dispatcher(dp)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Nothing happens after send_info_start() returns. The code does not reach the functions make_changes_vacation_days() #2 or make_changes_time_off_days() #3 not in normal mode, not in the debugger =(
I tried everything, including solutions on the Internet - nothing helps.